# Elasticsearch with NEST - How to ignore punctuation when searching

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

Using Elasticsearch I'm attempting to query an index with a string provided by a user. My documents contain punctuation which I'd like to preserve so they appear correctly when retrieved, however I don't want that punctuation to affect any search results whether or not it was provided in the query. For example:

Example document:

```
{ name: "joe's amazing document" }
```

When querying using the standard analyzer for `"joe's amazing document"` this works fine, however if the user types in `"joes amazing document"` this is not an exact match and the document gets lost amongst other low-scoring matches.

I've been searching to no avail so far to find how to do this with NEST - I suspect I may need to use a char_filter [such as this](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/excluding-punctuation-from-fields-td4002385.html#a4018580) but looking at the tests from NEST project source I can't see how to add my own custom char_filter with my own specified mapping, it only seems to allow me to specify a filter that Elasticsearch already knows about (extending [`CharFilterBase`](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest/Domain/Analysis/CharFilter/CharFilterBase.cs) only allows specifying the name of an existing filter to use)

Can anyone point me in the right direction with what I'm trying to do here? I'm aware I might be going about this all wrong so any help would be great - can I do this somehow with NEST or Elasticsearch, or do I need to customise Elasticsearch somehow? Or is there a solution out there which I've just been unable to find? Thanks!

**Update:** Thanks to femtoRgon's answer pointing me in the right direction please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22159076/1730317) below for how to use the [Snowball analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-snowball-analyzer.html) in NEST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to femtoRgon pointing me in the right direction, here is the solution I ended up using in NEST and the Snowball analyzer:

Firstly I added these attributes on my document class's properties where I wanted the analyzer used:

```
[ElasticType]
public class MyIndexItem {
    [ElasticProperty(IndexAnalyzer = "snowball", SearchAnalyzer = "snowball")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I recreated all indexes using a mapping from these attributes:

```
_client.CreateIndex(IndexName, s => s
    .AddMapping<MyIndexItem>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
 );
```

Finally I was able to index and query in the normal way with no extra config needed, with Elasticsearch only applying these analyzers when indexing/querying the fields with the attribute above.

Answer (score 2):

I believe contractions and possessives may be problematic for standard analyzer, since they are pretty language specific.  Compare:

- English: "Joe's amazing document"
- Spanish: "documento impresionante de Joe"
- German: "Joe erstaunliche dokument").

As such, a [language specific analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html) is probably the best solution.  EnglishAnalyzer includes an EnglishPossessiveFilter, which should handle this case.

You can set up an english analyzer something like:

```
index :
    analysis :
        analyzer :
            english :
                type : english
                stopwords : [...]
                stem_exclusion : [...]
```

`stopwords` and `stem_exclusion` are both optional.  Make sure, of course, the same analyzer is used at index and query time.

Comment: Thanks for this, however I found it only works the other way around - eg. if the document contains "joe amazing document" and the query is for the possessive form "joe's amazing document" (with or without apostrophe) then the EnglishAnalyzer correctly figures out this should still be the top match. However, when the document contains the possessive form "joe's amazing document", a query for "joes..." does not match. I guess I'll keep trying, thanks anyway.

Comment: That does seem odd.  Could be you are running into something odd in the stemmer, I suppose.  There are some oddball cases that it doesn't handle perfecty.  Are you sure that your EnglishAnalyzer was being applied for the query as well?

Comment: Yes I am testing various scenarios on two indexes with exactly the same data, one using each Analyzer, then running queries on each with the relevant Analyzer. I only notice a difference between the two sets of scores and the order of results when the query contains the possessive and the data does not.

Comment: Right, that disparity was what seemed to point to an analyzer mismatch to my mind.  I thought you might have hit an edge case with the word "Joe" in the stemmer, but that doesn't seem to be the case, judging by the output [this stemmer demonstration](http://snowball.tartarus.org/demo.php).  If you can show how you produce the query, that might reveal something.

Comment: I think I've recreated the scenario here: https://www.found.no/play/gist/70ba4ce6e4098a4627f8

Comment: I don't see how you are using the analyzer there.  I see the definition of an analyzer, but no [`index_analyzer` or `search_analyzer` definition](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html), nor anywhere the analyzer is [passed to the query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html).  It looks like you've set up and named an analyzer, but not used it anywhere.  When I add these, it seems to work as stated in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this pointed me in the right direction, I've now got it working in NEST.